# Optimal project organization and querysets

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models Company and Product with FK on Product:

```
class Product(Meta):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In case of a View that will gather company products what is the optimal approach(use infor form both models):

1) add the View in companies app and as queryset use:

`Company.objects.prefetch_related('products').get(pk=company_pk)`

2) add the View in products app and as queryset use:

`Product.objects.select_related('company').filter(company=company_pk)`

What about ordering can be chained with prefetch or select ?

Comment: Your queries do not yield the same results at all actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django docs illustrate the difference quite well:

> `prefetch_related(*lookups)`
>
> Returns a QuerySet that will
>   automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of
>   the specified lookups.
>
> This has a similar purpose to select_related, in that both are
>   designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by
>   accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different.
>
> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields
>   of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason,
>   select_related gets the related objects in the same database query.
>   However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from
>   joining across a ‘many’ relationship, **select_related is limited to
>   single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.**
>
> `select_related(*fields)`
>
> **Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships,
>   selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.**
>   This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex
>   query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require
>   database queries.